# From a range, return a specific word's index

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a range (`rng`) which has the word "means" somewhere in it.  I'm trying to determine if a word two words before "means" is underlined but can't quite figure out how.

Here's what my `rng.Text` is (note the brackets indicate the underlined text)

`"[Automobile] - means a car that isn't a bus but can be an SUV"`

Sometimes, it is `"The way you have to go about it is with the various means of thinking"`.

The first one is a definition, since it has "means" preceeded by an underlined word.  The second example is NOT a definition.

I'm trying to get my macro to look to 2 word *before* "means", but can't quite figure out how.

I am able to figure how many characters it is by this:

```
Dim meansLoc&
meansLoc = instr(rng.Text, "means")
```

Then, I can test `If rng.Characters(meansLoc-9).Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle`, but I run into problems if my defined word is only say 3 characters ("Dad - means a father", would error our since there means' index is 7, and 7-9 = -2).  This is why I'd like to use words.  (I can use one or two words before "means").

How can I return the character index of "means" in my `rng`.  How do I get the "word index" (i.e. 2) from my `rng`?

Comment: Remember MoveEnd? Well, there's also a Move method that uses the same parameters. Take a look at that in the Help, look at the WdUnits Enum and give it a try :-) Move the Range backwards (negative Count value), get its Word (Range.Words(1)) then test Font.Underline...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Characters and Words are ranges, so one approach would be to compare the Start of the Character's range with each Word in the rng, e.g. you could start with

```
' assumes you have already declared and populated rng

Dim bDefinition As Boolean
Dim i as Integer
Dim meansLoc as Integer
Dim meansStart as Integer
meansLoc = instr(rng.Text,"means")
meansStart = rng.Characters(meansLoc).Start
bDefinition = False
For i = 1 To rng.Words.Count
  If rng.Words(i).Start = meansStart Then ' i is your Word index (i.e. 3, not 2!)
    If i > 2 Then
      If rng.Words(i - 2).Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle Then
        Debug.Print "Looks like a definition"
        bDefinition = True
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
  End If
Next
If Not bDefinition Then
  Debug.Print "Couldn't see a definition"
End If
```

Just bear in mind that what Word considers to be a "word" may be different from your normal understanding of what a "word" is.